# VMware tools ported for Fedora 11 VM?

Tags: vmware-tools, fedora

With Fedora 11 being so new and using a newer Linux kernel, the VMware tools don't compile so can't be directly used in an F11 VM.  I can get around to porting them myself, but has anyone else run into this and fixed it yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [patch available](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/203231) for vmware for Fedora11

Comment: I should also note that for me, the patch got it to build, but once I exited from a VM, I could no longer start VMs until I rebooted.  Wound up going back to F10 for now.  (This may have been fixed in the past month though.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use Xen or KVM.

However if you must use vmware ESX,ESXi or Vfail; consider checking out

http://open-vm-tools.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Try using open-vm-tools from RPM Fusion repository:

yum install open-vm-tools